# JSON.stringify not returning expected objects

Tags: javascript, json, websocket

I've been playing about with Node.js and Websockets recently. I'm getting there with it, however there's an odd issue regarding JSON.stringify (client side).

I like to use JSON.stringify to determine which object properties the server is returning..

So for example, I have the following snippet of code:

```
ws.onmessage = function(param1) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(param1));
}
```

This displays an alert box of `{"isTrusted" : true}`

Because of this output, I thought my server wasn't sending a message back to the client. Out of curiousity, I decided to just modify the alert function to

`alert(param1.data);`

The expected message was there! So my question is why didn't JSON.stringify include a `data` object when it was evidently there?

Comment: don't use alert for debugging asynchronous requests

Comment: @charlietfl: ...or basically anything else.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`JSON.stringify`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-json.stringify) includes only the *own, enumerable* properties of an object in the output; this is covered by the abstract [SerializeJSONObject](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-serializejsonobject) operation in the spec. That means that inherited properties, and non-enumerable properties, are left out.

Apparently, the only own, enumerable property on your message was `isTrusted`.

Gratuitous Example:

```js
function Thingy(name, age) {
  // Save `name` as an own, enumerable property
  this.name = name;
  
  // Save `age` as an own, non-enumerable property
  Object.defineProperty(this, "age", {
    value: age
  });
}

// Define `what` as a property that will be inherited by
// all `Thingy` instances:
Thingy.prototype.what = "evs";

// Create one
var t = new Thingy("foo", 42);

// Get the JSON for it:
console.log(JSON.stringify(t)); // {"name":"foo"}
```

---

The take-away message here, though, is that there's virtually no place for `alert`-style debugging in 2016. Instead of stumbling around in the dark with an `alert` (or `console.log`) torch, *turn on the lights* by using the powerful, fully-featured debugger built into your browser: Put a breakpoint on the first statement in your handler, and when the breakpoint is reached, examine the contents of `param1` dynamically. It will show you both own properties and inherited ones, enumerable ones and non-enumerable ones, with their current values with the JavaScript code suspended.

Comment: you may use the _debugger__ sentence:
check out: [link](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_debugger.asp)

Comment: @Loksly: Please link to a reputable source, such as MDN, not that unreliable one. And if you're using the fully-featured debugger built into your browser, you don't *need* a `debugger;` statement; that's what breakpoints are for.

Comment: You are right, this is the right source: 
[debugger statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger)