# Cannot read drag and dropped file with FileReader

Tags: javascript, angular, html, typescript, angular6

I am attempting to allow for an image to be uploaded to my site via a drag and drop to my site by dragging and dropping an image onto a specific div on the page:

```
<div class="container" (drop)="onDrop($event)" (dragover)="onDragOver($event)" (dragleave)="onDragLeave($event)">
    <img id="blah" [src]="url || 'http://placehold.it/180'" alt="your image" />

</div>
```

I have all of the drop related events fiting, I however been unable to actually get the image from FileReader:

What am I doing wrong? my drop related functions from the controller are below for reference.

```
onDrop(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    this.file = event.dataTransfer.files[0];
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = e => {
        this.url = reader.result;
        console.log(this.url);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(this.file);
    this.fileDraggedOverDiv = false;
}

onDragOver(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    this.fileDraggedOverDiv = true;
    return false;
}

onDragLeave(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    this.fileDraggedOverDiv = false;
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are actually successfully passing the file to the `onDrop` event. Its just that you can't see it when `console.log(JSON.stringify(event));` executes, because inherited properties, and non-enumerable properties, are left out as pointed out in [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39961788/5899903).

To get the image from the event you need to do as follows.

```
onDrop(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const file = event.dataTransfer.files[0];
}
```

See this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ondrop) for a full working example.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help. How should I go about displaying the image? I am using  FileReader.readDataAsUrl() to try and get a url for the image and it does not seem to be working.

Comment: @TylerB.Joudrey It works as I have done so in my own project. Make sure you define the `reader.onload` event, and in the event, you set the src value of the image element. Also if my answer worked for you, please accept the answer.

Comment: I have defined it as `reader.onload = e => {
            this.url = reader.result;
            console.log(this.url);
        };`

Comment: And the url still does not work, So I cannot accept the answer until it does.

Comment: @TylerB.Joudrey It will be hard to tell whats wrong with your code without seeing it. Have a look at the stackblitz link I added to the answer and let me know if you manage to get your code working through referencing that.